# MyMonero wallet compatible with CPUminer/MinerGate

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, web-wallet

I followed the tutorial on https://www.electromaker.io/tutorial/blog/cryptocurrency-mining-on-the-raspberry-pi-60 (mining monero obviously) and everything worked well... Code is compiled and can be started... But in this tutorial the mining deamon is started using `./minerd -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xmr.pool.minergate.com:45560 -u youremail@address.com -p x -t 4` where the -u flag is the username and -p the password...

I have a wallet at MyMonero and not at MinerGate... Can I use CPUminer with a MyMonero account as well? If yes how? And what wallet do you prefer and why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your username (-u) will be your MyMonero wallet address instead of your minergate registered email address. As far as im aware thats how it works with XMRig and Castxmr, don't see why it would be different for CPUminer

Comment: but what's the password then? mymonero has only the 13 words for authentification...

Comment: Leave the password as "x" , you don't need a password if its pointed to your wallet address because the mining rewards are going to your wallet which is -u "yourMyMoneroaddress"